# IVPort raspberry pi camera module

Tags: raspberry-pi, multiplexer, camera

Im trying to design multiplex camera system for my raspberry pi something like this https://www.tindie.com/products/canerdurmusoglu/ivport-dual-v2-raspberry-pi-camera-multiplexer/#product-description

Does anyone knows, what kind of chip is on a board like this, something like 14bit bus 2:1 mux. But I cant find something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..something like 14bit bus 2:1 mux

Unlikely. The Raspberry-Pi camera interfaces are MIPI CSI ports. You can't use a normal multiplexer.

> what kind of chip is on a board like this?

Look for a MIPI multiplexer.

Comment: Thank you, its helpfull. Those 14bits bus are hard to find.